# How to Bookmark Duplicate lines

Tags: notepad++

I have a big list of Domains like this:

```
Example.com
Apple.com
Google.com
Google.com
Example.com
Yahoo.com
Apple.com
```

What I want is to bookmark all duplicate domains and remove all duplicates and only output which is only unique , in this above example case it is only Yahoo.com

How can it be done ?

Comment: Would `translate.google.com` and `mail.google.com` be unique or not?

Comment: all are root domains , no sub domains in the list

Comment: Is every domain in one line? A small example as text excerpt is always helpful!

Comment: Its like below :

0024takanori.jp
0024takanori.jp
007.com
0101.co.jp
0101.co.jp
013.nl
013.nl
01net.com
01net.com
01net.com
01netTV.com
0415.co.kr
04limitedsazabys.com
04limitedsazabys.com
0i.is
0kiss.jp
0kiss.jp
0x.org
0x.org
1-2-1hockeycoaching.co.uk
1-2-1hockeycoaching.co.uk

Comment: Yes one domain in each line , i want to remove duplicates totally and only leave which are unique

Comment: Are all domains sorted? Is it allowed to sort them before removing duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

If you can sort the domains, here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^.+)\R(?:\1(?:\R|\z))+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(^.+)       # group 1, 1 or more any character
(?:         # non capture group
  \R          # any kind of linebreak
  \1          # backreference to group 1
  (?:\R|\z)   # non capture group, a linebreak or end of file
)+          # end group, must appear 1 or more times
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]